# Database connectivity error

Tags: php, database

In the below code when I pass `$id_num` to check the id field in database it accepts but when I want to pass user id to check with database it shows the following error;

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in line no 12

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong.

**code:**

```
if(isset($_POST['user_mail']) && isset($_POST['user_pass']))
{
    $var_1=$_POST["user_mail"];
    $var_2=$_POST["user_pass"];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jsrao_db2 WHERE user_mail=$var_1");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
            if(($row['user_mail']==$var_1) && ($row['user_pass']==$var_2))//compare user name and password with database value
            echo "Welcome";
            else
            echo "Try Again";
    }
```

Comment: Run This Query on mysql terminal or in phpmyadmin first. make sure query return data from table.

Comment: the same code works when i use <br> if (isset($_REQUEST))
 {
 $id_num=$_REQUEST["id"];
 
 $id=1;
 echo"<table border='1'>";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jsrao_db1 where Id=$id_num"); //print table
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))

Comment: @Fred-ii- - markdown can be confusing in the beginning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your query

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jsrao_db2 WHERE user_mail=$var_1");<br>
```

should be

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jsrao_db2 WHERE user_mail='$var_1'");<br>
```

user_mail is an string so enclose $var_1 in '$var_1'

Comment: I'd at least recommend using prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for cleaning up your code:

```
$result = false;
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM jsrao_db2 WHERE user_mail=?");
$stmt->bind_result($result);
$result = $stmt->bind_param("s", $var_1)->execute();
if ($result) {
    //work with $result
}
```